# What is the syntax when defining rules in eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I started using eslint but I found there are variances in rules syntax. However I couldn't find in the eslint docs what is the general syntax.

First, I notice that each rule is specified in form of key-value pair. The key is the rule ID in form of a string and that's fine. But what is the syntax for the value assigned to this key? From various examples online I saw it can be a number, array, object... and possibly something more?

Here are some examples I found:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "eqeqeq": 0,
        "quotes": [2, "double"],
        "getter-return": ["error", { "allowImplicit": true }],
        "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }]
    }
}
```

In [getting started guide](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration) it is only noted the meaning of the first element when using the array syntax. But I couldn't find comprehensive explanation of syntax in general.

Also in docs there is the usage of term `options` like [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi#options). What exactly is this `options` in the context of a rule? It seems to me that this is the value of elements that come after first element in array but I am not sure.

Comment: It depends on the rule, and is explained in the respective rule's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Value is always going to be an array. Array items might contain strings, other arrays or objects, that's specific to each particular rule, and you can look up all available options in the rule's documentation on ESLint website (https://eslint.org/docs/rules). First item in the array will always be state of the rule, and can be either a string or number ("off" = 0, "warn" = 1, "error" = 2). You can get more information about config syntax of eslint here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules